# Choose activity dynamically during splashscreen

Tags: java, android, json, mobile

I'm doing a small project, and today I had to make a conditional validation in splashscreen. The project was practically finalized when we decided to do this validation in splashscreen.

Modified my class and was working ok, but I had to include the time for the splash disappears (variable SPLASH_TIME_OUT) and started giving an error that I do not understand.

My splashscreen clas (now) is:

```
package com.clubee.vote;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Splashscreen extends Activity {

// Splash screen timer

private static String url_Pesquisa_voto = "http://dev.clubee.com.br/dbvote/PesquisaVoto.php";
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

public String retrieveMacAddress(Context context) {
    WifiManager wfman = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    String macAddress = wfman.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
    if (macAddress == null) {
        macAddress = "Dispositivo sem endereço mac address ou wi-fi desabilitado";
    }
    return macAddress;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new PesquisaVoto().execute();
}


class PesquisaVoto extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Splashscreen.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Pesquisando Voto..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;
        WifiManager wfman = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        String macAddress = wfman.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
        if (macAddress == null) {
            macAddress = "Dispositivo sem endereço mac";
        }

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("macAddress", macAddress));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_Pesquisa_voto, "GET", params);

        // check log cat from response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);


            if (success == 1) {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        Intent i = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, ResultadoFalho.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                        finish();
                    }
                }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
            } else {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Intent i = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                        finish();
                    }
                }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

   }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> 03-03 17:38:49.882  10432-10450/com.clubee.vote D/Create Response﹕ {"voto":[{"count":"1"}],"success":1}
>   03-03 17:38:49.882  10432-10450/com.clubee.vote W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4164dd88)
>   03-03 17:38:49.892  10432-10450/com.clubee.vote E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>       Process: com.clubee.vote, PID: 10432
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done

Anyone knows what I did wrong? Is it possivel to implement the Runnable inside the IF statement? If I do not put the timeout variable, everything is right.

UPDATE THE LOG WITH ERROR

> 03-03 22:01:50.016  18731-18746/com.clubee.vote W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4164dd88)
>   03-03 22:01:50.026  18731-18746/com.clubee.vote E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>       Process: com.clubee.vote, PID: 18731
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>               at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:200)
>               at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:114)
>               at com.clubee.vote.Splashscreen$PesquisaVoto.doInBackground(Splashscreen.java:87)
>               at com.clubee.vote.Splashscreen$PesquisaVoto.doInBackground(Splashscreen.java:48)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>   03-03 22:01:50.697  18731-18731/com.clubee.vote E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.clubee.vote.Splashscreen has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{44aa2458 V.E..... R......D 0,0-681,345} that was originally added here
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:350)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>               at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:294)
>               at com.clubee.vote.Splashscreen$PesquisaVoto.onPreExecute(Splashscreen.java:58)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
>               at com.clubee.vote.Splashscreen.onCreate(Splashscreen.java:44)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   03-03 22:01:52.529  18731-18746/com.clubee.vote I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 18731 SIG: 9

Answer (score 1):

Tks in advance for answers and comments. I corrected my code, re-wrote and re-structured it, became easier to see where the mistakes were.

below, I leave the code that is working for future research. thank you very much

```
package com.clubee.vote;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Splashscreen extends Activity {

// Splash screen timer

private static String url_Pesquisa_voto = "http://dev.clubee.com.br/dbvote/PesquisaVoto.php";
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private  static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;

public String retrieveMacAddress(Context context) {
    WifiManager wfman = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    String macAddress = wfman.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
    if (macAddress == null) {
        macAddress = "Dispositivo sem endereço mac address ou wi-fi desabilitado";
    }
    return macAddress;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            new PesquisaVoto().execute();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}

class PesquisaVoto extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Splashscreen.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Pesquisando Voto..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        WifiManager wfman = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        String macAddress = wfman.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
        if (macAddress == null) {
            macAddress = "Dispositivo sem endereço mac";
        }

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("macAddress", macAddress));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_Pesquisa_voto, "GET", params);

        // check log cat from response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);


            if (success == 1) {


                Intent i = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, ResultadoFalho.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
            else {


                Intent i = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot clearly see what is wrong based on the Logs you provided but there is something wrong with your structure.

You are starting an Activity within doInBackground Process and then dismissing the Progress Dialog which belongs to the Activity that you just finished.

Try to pass a parameter to the onPostExecute and then finish your Activity there.

And post some more details from your Log to make it clear. There has to be some more logs indicating what went wrong.

Comment: Hello @osayilgan, after modified the code, with your suggestion, the same problem occurred. Follow the log, like you asked.

Comment: so after you logs, I can easily say where it was wrong. You were creating an Handler inside of the AsycnTask. If you create the handler instance out side of the asyncTask, like in on create, problem will be solved.